# Glide not loading image in phone, only in desktop browser (Android)

Tags: android, kotlin, http, responsive-design, android-glide

I'm trying to get an image from an URL using Glide.

This image belongs in a carousel where the other images load correctly.

The problem is that the image doesn't load, and when opened in a browser it shows correctly, but when I open up the device toolbar, select a phone and refresh it just shows a 404 error.

I don't know what is causing this error, I've tried using `.override()` and adding some headers manually but nothing seems to work.

I managed to make it work with Picasso but we can't implement it at this point of the project.

This is my glide code right now:

```
        Glide.with(binding.offerImage.context)
        .asBitmap()
        .load(url)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_offers_placeholder)
        .override(2048, 1024)
        .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
            override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                binding.offerImage.setImageBitmap(resource)
            }

            override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
                // Do Nothing
            }
        })
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` permission to your manifest?

Comment: Hello Luca, as I said the other images on the carousel load fine. This project is very big and quite old so obviously we didn't forget about the internet permission, thanks for your time anyway!

Comment: Tell us more about the image. Are there funny letters in the URL? Is the image format the same as the other ones? Is the size the same?

Comment: We've been working on it and it seems it's a User-Agent header problem, the image is the same resolution, format and size as the others. It seems like a backend problem.